# How to catch CheckBox changed event in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am changing the value of a cell of type DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn (check and uncheck a CheckBox) in the DataGridView control. Is there any way to catch this event? CellEndEdit event fires only if I select another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can check try `CellValueChanged` event, but hooking an event doesn't seems to be possible and as you would have observed it happens as soon as you move out of the cell. This tells the Grid that Editing is complete for the cell.

I vaguely remember doing something like in the mouseup event for the cell make sure to do `DataDrigView1.EndEdit()` and this should help you rollout your logic in the CellValueChanged event by checking the checked state. (Sorry cannot test it as of now)

[Or maybe this might work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/2a573499-294a-4493-ba0b-aad301d9e9ef)